# Assign has_and_belongs_to_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have:

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
 ...
 has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
 ...
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
 ...
 has_and_belongs_to_many  :offers
 ...
end
```

and

```
def create
 ...
 @offer = @commercial_activity.offers.build(offer_params)
 tagsname = params[:tags].split(',')
 for tag in tagsname
   @offer.tags = Tag.find_or_create_by(name: tag, city_id: @commercial_activity.city)
  end
  ...
end
```

When I create a new offers I have this error:

```
undefined method `each' for #<Tag:0x9fcc918>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What does the backtrace say? Does it give you a specific line number to reference?

Comment: the error is on the line: @offer.tags = Tag.find_or_create_by(name: tag, city_id: @commercial_activity.city)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.find_or_create_by` returns a single object, not a collection. `@offer.tags =` needs to be set to a collection, not a single object.

You can use `@offer.tags << Tag.find_or_create_by`

I'd recommend adding a `uniq` constraint if you take this approach, too, so that you dont have multiple tag associations with the same tag.